# C# / Unity / Linq - How to check if a list of lists contains a specific another list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, graph

I've got a list of list of ints like such:

```
    public List<List<int>> Paths = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int>{0,1 },
        new List<int>{1,2 },
        new List<int>{1,3 },
        new List<int>{2,3 },
        new List<int>{2,4 },
        new List<int>{3,4 },
        new List<int>{4,5 },
    };
```

and I've got a path, that is just a list of int:

```
List<int> path = new List<int>{4,5};
```

How can I check if `Paths` contains `path`?
I've tried `if(Paths.Contains(path))` and it always yields `false`, even though I know I've got a list of `{4, 5}` in there.

I'm working on a project for unity and I've read some magic can be done using linq, so I tagged it in the title topic for future google users. ;)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit:
I came up with this temporary solution, but I feel it can be done more elegant:

```
        public bool CheckIfPathsHaveConnection(List<int> connection)
        {
            bool hasElement = false;
            foreach(List<int> path in Paths)
            {
                if(path[0] == connection[0] && path[1] == connection[1])
                {
                    hasElement = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    hasElement = false;
                }
            }
            return hasElement;
        }
```

EDIT2:
Thank you all for your replies, I really appreciate the effort. Every answer was helpful and worthy of a solution, unfortunately I can only pick one as solution, so I'm picking the one that explained the most.

Comment: It always yields false, because it compares list references, not values contained in those lists

Comment: Superb, and how can I make sure it compares values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Paths.Contains(path))
```

in your case returns always `false` since `List<T>` is a class => reference type and you checked for reference equality (it needs to be exactly the same instance of a list) but you created a `new` one.

For actual lists and more in general you could use

```
using System.Linq;

...

// If you use array or list doesn't matter for Linq / IEnumerable
var index = paths.FindIndex(p => p.SequenceEqual(new []{1, 2});
if(index >= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

returns either the index of the first encountered list with equal items in the same order or `-1` if none was found.

See

- [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal)
- [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex#system-collections-generic-list-1-findindex(system-predicate((-0))))

---

However, if there are always only and exactly two items anyway then I would not use lists at all but rather have a proper implementation using [`IEquatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) and especially [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode) (which is used for any hash based collections like `Dictionary`, `HashSet` etc) like e.g.

```
public class Path : IEquatable<Path>
{
    public int Start;
    public int End;

    public Path(int start, int end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Start.GetHashCode() ^ End.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Path path)
    {
        return path.Start == Start && path.End == End;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || ! (obj is Path path))
            return false;
        else
            return Equals(path);
    }

    public static bool operator == (Path a, Path b)
    {
        if (((object)a) == null || ((object)b) == null)
            return object.Equals(a, b);

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator != (Path a, Path b)
    {
        if (((object)a) == null || ((object)b) == null)
            return ! object.Equals(a, b);

        return ! (a.Equals(b));
    }
}
```

And then you could simply have a

```
public List<Path> Paths = new List<Path>
{
    new Path (0,1),
    new Path (1,2),
    new Path (1,3),
    ....
}
```

and get the index without using Linq at all

```
// Since you now properly implemented Equals this now compares
// the values rather than the reference
var index = paths.IndexOf(new Path(1, 2));
if(index >= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is very explanatory, especially in parts I didn't get. 
It's not as straightforward, but definitely worthwhile read. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (Paths.Any(x => x[0] == path[0] && x[1] == path[1]))`

Comment: that looks pretty, is there a way to get the index of the element that matched my querry?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a linq solution you could use a combination of [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) and [`All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-6.0):

```
var containsPath = Paths.Any(p => p                 // any sub-list in 'Paths'
                           .All(q =>                // all elements of sub-list
                               path.Contains(q)));  // are contained in 'path'
```

Comment: This doesn't ensure the same order though ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know an index of existed path try this

```
    var index = IfExist(paths,path);
    
    var exist = index >= 0;
    
    public int IfExist(List<List<int>> paths, List<int> path)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count; i++)
            if (paths[i][0] == path[0] && (paths[i][1] == path[1])) return i;
         
         return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to test and see if any of the paths in `Paths` is equal to the `path`:

```
var ans = Paths.Any(p => p.SequenceEqual(path));
```